# Sign a .zip file to allow people verify the authenticity of its content

Tags: openssl, digital-signature, sign, verify

Assuming this:

- i want to distribute a software through my web site download page
- i want allow people verify its authenticity

is openssl the right tool to do it? And which are exactly the steps i have to go through in order to do so?

As far as i understood, i have to:

- create a new key-pair (locally on my PC, not on the server)
- every time i need to create or update the .zip of my software, i sign it locally and then i upload it to the server
- people will then download the .zip  from my server and i will have to distribute the pubkey (for example writing it on the download page)
- once the user has the file on his HDD, he may verify that the signature of the .zip file matches the pubkey

are those steps right? any suggestion?

thanks

Comment: Usually pgp/gpg is used in such a case

Comment: could you extend a bit your point? even as answer to the question.. thanks

Comment: https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/x135.html